# How can I use a dynamic select form to change style in HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, onchange

I am new just started a course on JS and wanted to have fun on an assignment but perhaps got a little ahead of myself. I decided to do a simple recreation of The Bridge of Death from Monty Python

I am trying to use JS in a HTML file to create a dropdown menu and then when a certain option is selected it changes the color of the paragraph elements.

I am unsure how to pull the values of the options created in the select form to style the element.
What I have now creates the dropdown but the options don't change anything

Sorry if this is super janky, I literally started a week ago.

Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>The Bridge of Death!!!</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>You Approach the Bridge of Death</h1>
  <button id="q1button" onclick="q1_func()">Talk to Tim </button>
  <p id="question_1"></p>
  <p id="response_1"></p>

  <script>
    function q1_func() {
      const name = prompt("What is your Name", "Arthur, King of the Britains");
      if (name != null) {
        document.getElementById("question_1").innerHTML = "What is Your Name?";
        document.getElementById("response_1").innerHTML = "My name is " + name;
        document.getElementById("q1button").remove();
        q2_func();
      }
    }
  </script>
  <p id="question_2"></p>
  <p id="response_2"></p>
  <script>
    function q2_func() {
      var quest = prompt("What is your Quest", "To seek the Holy Grail!");
      if (quest != null) {
        document.getElementById("question_2").innerHTML = "What is Your Quest?";
        document.getElementById("response_2").innerHTML = quest;
        q3_func();
      }
    }
  </script>
  <p id="question_3"></p>
  <p id="response_3"></p>
  <script>
    function changeBackground(colors) {
      var val = list.options[list.selectedIndex].values;
      document.p.style.backgroundColor = val;
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    function q3_func() {
      var values = [" ", "blue", "red", "pink", "blue...no..."];
      var select = document.createElement("select");
      select.name = "colors";
      select.id = "colors";
      select.onchange = "changeBackground(this)";

      for (const val of values) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.values = val;
        option.text = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
        select.appendChild(option);
      }

      var label = document.createElement("label");
      label.innerHTML = "What is you favorite color?";
      label.htmlFor = "color";

      document.getElementById("question_3").appendChild(label).appendChild(select);
      document.getElementById("q2_button").remove();
      if (value === "blue...no...") {
        alert("Ahhhhh!!!!! *Death* ");
      };
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I feel like there is a better way to create the select form. I could also use html to create it and then hide then reveal it in the q2_func.

Any suggestions on where I could go from here?
Some limitations based on the assignment: no seperate files for js or css, just use js to change the style (no jquery or ajax)

Also the "blue...no..." should lead to an alert but that isn't working either...

Thank you in advance!
-Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code solution.

1. If you want to add onchange function you need to use setAttribute function to add onchange function on selectbox in **q3_func()**.
2. You didn't defined any list veriable in changeBackground function that you want to use in that function event that you're getting colors parameter and you can use **colors.options** and **colors.selectIndex**
3. You can't use **document.p** directly because p is not defined as veriable or it's not a document but it's a part of document. You can use **document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]** [0] indecate index of tags.
   **For example:**

Your are using p tag 5 time in body [0] indecates first p tag and [1] indecates to 2nd.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">

            <head>
            <title>The Bridge of Death!!!</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            </head>

            <body>
             <h1>You Approach the Bridge of Death</h1>
             <button id="q1button" onclick="q1_func()">Talk to Tim </button>
              <p id="question_1"></p>
             <p id="response_1"></p>

            <script>
            function q1_func() {
              const name = prompt("What is your Name", "Arthur, King of the Britains");
              if (name != null) {
                document.getElementById("question_1").innerHTML = "What is Your Name?";
                document.getElementById("response_1").innerHTML = "My name is " + name;
                document.getElementById("q1button").remove();
                q2_func();
              }
            }
           </script>
            <p id="question_2"></p>
            <p id="response_2"></p>

            <script>
            function q2_func() {
              var quest = prompt("What is your Quest", "To seek the Holy Grail!");
              if (quest != null) {
                document.getElementById("question_2").innerHTML = "What is Your Quest?";
                document.getElementById("response_2").innerHTML = quest;
                q3_func();
              }
            }
          </script>

            <p id="question_3"></p>
            <p id="response_3"></p>
             <script>
              function changeBackground(colors) {
              var val = colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].values;
              document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.backgroundColor = val;
            }
          </script>

             <script>
                function q3_func() {
              var values = [" ", "blue", "red", "pink", "blue...no..."];
              var select = document.createElement("select");
              select.name = "colors";
              select.id = "colors";
              select.setAttribute("onchange", "changeBackground(this)");

              for (const val of values) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.values = val;
                option.text = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
                select.appendChild(option);
              }

              var label = document.createElement("label");
              label.innerHTML = "What is you favorite color?";
              label.htmlFor = "color";

              document.getElementById("question_3").appendChild(label).appendChild(select);
              document.getElementById("q2_button").remove();
              if (value === "blue...no...") {
                alert("Ahhhhh!!!!! *Death* ");
               };
              }
              </script>
            </body>

        </html>
```

I hope you understand this.

Comment: This works! Is there a way to select each p in that one line or do I need seperate lines for each one. I tried [0,-1] to try and get all but it didn't work... Also the alert for selecting "Blue...no..." isn't working. Any ideas how to fix that? I tried moving the if statement into the changeBackground script at the end so far ----Thank you so much for the kind response btw! I do think I understand what you did.

Comment: `function changeBackground(colors) {
        var val = colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].values;
        var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
   {
       paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor = val;
   }
      }`



Replace this function with changeBackground(colors)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the alert trigger!
Using the changes Abdul made I added the following code to the end of the changeBackground function:

```
var x = document.getElementById("colors").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("colors").options;
if (y[x].index === 4){
alert("Ahhhhgggg!!! .... *Death*");
};
```

It works completely now.
Thank you

Kevin